# Collapsible regions in advance editing mode via Designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, html-editor

Is there a way to enable SharePoint Designer 2010 (in advance mode), to show collapse/expand markers so that I can hide curtain sections on my .aspx pages I am not modifying?

Comment: I've been using SPD for over 7 years and haven't seen this as an option, if I've missed it and there is a config option for this I'll be happy!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and this is why I manually bring code over to Dreamweaver or Notepad++, code there with features like collapsible regions, and then bring it back into Designer.

Comment: its not possible!, and I know it sucks! I paste my code in notepad++

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting, you could right-click on the file, then click "Open-With" and select your editor of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible, even in 2013: http://wehatesharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/sharepoint-designer-13-preview-still-no.html

I need to do research whether it's possible to write a custom add on (just like Office ones) for SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 as it's a pain to scroll through a lot of code you are not interested in whilst using SPD :).